# Relative Jedi Proficiency With The Force

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi, the-force

I know that there are many Force proficient groups and organisations in the Star Wars galaxy. I was wondering how skillful the Jedi are with the force relative to other force-using groups.

**Are the Jedi truly masters of the Force compared to other organisations, or are they sub-par compared to most others?**

It's alright if your answer is not in the official canon, I'm just curious about any books or stories that might be relevant to my question.

Comment: Hi Josh,  welcome to stackexchange. Have you seen our [tour]? You seem to be mixing up Jedi's profession with species.

Comment: @joshb The Jedi is an organisation of Force-sensitive beings from all the different species you mentioned - not an individual species of their own. If you reword your question to ask about the proficiency of the Jedi in the Force relative to other groups/organisations in the galaxy, then this question will be answerable. You may also want to state what canonicity of answers you are seeking in that case too.

Comment: @thegreatjedi Thanks for the suggestion. I have clarified my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

There are the Voss mystics, force sensitive "seers" on Voss. They use their connection to the Force to predict the future through seeing visions, to aid the communities decision makings.

The Voss mystics rarely have visions, but when they do, they aren't wrong, whereas the Jedi have visions more often, but they aren't always as clear. It's a bit more powerful, but the Voss don't normally use other applications of the Force, such as telekinesis, mind tricks, and the darker arts such as force lightning, force choke, and using the force to augment ones own physical abilities.

Another species would be a native species on Felucia, aptly named "Felucians", but they're more receptive to the Force than being able to use it.

Comment: This quite a nice answer! Any references you can add? That would add even more value.

Comment: starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Voss_Mystics

Comment: Bear in mind, stuff from SWTOR isnt strictly canon, more qualified as Star Wars Extended Universe. Id say all in all, the Jedi are above most any other organizations involving the Force, due to the incredibly diverse and detailed instruction on using the Force, beat possibly only by the Sith in mastery.